# Postfix: unlimited per-user addresses via "+" sign

Tags: email, postfix

Gmail users can [get virtually unlimited email addresses](http://gmailblog.blogspot.de/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html) by using `$name+$suffix@gmail.com` ("plus addressing").

I'd like to have that for my own mail server, which is running Postfix. The mailbox and alias data are stored in a MySQL database.

I suspect that the alias configuration needs to be modified, so that `user+foo@example.org` gets mapped to the `user@example.org` mailbox, but I fail to find out how.

So, is it possible? How?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apart from setting

```
recipient_delimiter = +
```

I also had to modify `master.cf`, so that maildrop gets not only the recipient passed, but the real user:

```
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=Debian-exim argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${user}@${nexthop} ${extension} ${recipient} ${user} ${nexthop}
```

Blog post: http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/postfix-plus-addressing.htm

Comment: You asked about `postfix`, yet this mentions `exim`, which is different SMTP server. BTW, note that if you have real IMAP server (not just mailbox), using `LMTP` is much faster than maildrop. And if you use LMTP with Cyrus, you will not need this.

Comment: the user is debian-exim, but it's still postfix.

Comment: http://www.postfix.org/MAILDROP_README.html

Comment: Saved my day with `{nexthop}`. I didn't even knew that existed. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answered. It helped me a lot. I am using postfix + procmail + dovecot in a virtualmin server. I just added the "recipient_delimiter = +" line and the plus addressing looks to be working fine. Should I do anything additional for procmail or dovecot? Also, is it possible to restrict this domain-wise? So that I can enable this plus addressing only for some domains on my server? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You did not say what mail server is storing your emails. These days, it should be one of the IMAP servers - like Cyrus, Dovecot, Courier, ...

I personally like Cyrus IMAP. It supports this with [relative ease](http://www.cyrusimap.org/docs/cyrus-imapd/2.4.17/faq.php):

> **Plus addressing** - allows direct delivery to a particular mailbox (other than an INBOX). This is done via an address of the form: username+mailfolder@domain, which will deliver to the user's INBOX.mailfolder folder (or altnamespace equivalent). This submailbox must allow the posting user the 'p' right.

Adding 'p' right is important step - otherwise all mail (using `+` or not) will be delivered to username INBOX.

Note that you should use `LMTP` (local mail transport protocol) to deliver your mail from `postfix` to `IMAP` server and also need to configure postfix `recipient_delimiter` (or `recipient_delimiters`) as [described here](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html):

```
recipient_delimiter = +
```

Comment: as long as the mails do not reach the user/maildrop because the mail address is not recognized by the receiving server, IMAP server support does not matter.

Comment: thanks for giving the hint about "plus adressing". with that name, I found the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The `master.cf` line for Dovecot:

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
 -f ${sender} -a ${recipient} -d ${user}@${domain}
```

With Postfix 2.4 and earlier, use `${nexthop}` instead of `${domain}`

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LDA/Postfix

Comment: Thanks. Ideed, The postfix solution alone is not enough if you use Dovecot. You'll need this extra config for Dovecot.